# Using wp-cli : wp post meta add adds an extra string at the start of the value

Tags: wordpress, metadata

A colleague uses [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/)  to work with scripts for wordpress data migration/alteration. We had a weird issue with one operation. Following is an example of the command that is executed:

```
wp post meta add '2677' "_wp_attachment_metadata" 'a:5:{s:5:"width";i:0;s:6:"height";i:0;s:4:"file";s:35:"Uttar-Pradesh_Agra_View-at-Agra.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:1:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:47:"/uploads150/Uttar-Pradesh_Agra_View-at-Agra.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}'
```

It inserts data in to the database, but it appends a string such as 's:484:' before the value "a:1:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4...."

ie : s:484:"a:1:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4....}"

Seems like string length. It shouldn't add that. What could be doing it? Am I missing a flag/switch with the command ?

**Note**: Some one please add wp-cli to tag list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are serializing an already serialized string.

```
$a = array('a','b');
//array(2) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(1) "a"
//  [1]=>
//  string(1) "b"
//}
$b = serialize($a);
//string(30) a:2:{i:0;s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";}
$c = serialize($b);
//string(38) s:30:"a:2:{i:0;s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";}";
```

That's exactly the output you have.

Or, to put it the other way around: You are providing a serialized object to wp-cli, which serializes it again. The solution would be to provide the array directly to wp-cli, without running it through `serialize()` before.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when I tried to update post meta using function "update_post_meta". An extra string was being appended before and after actual string.

Simple solution is to pass an array instead of serialized data.